# Static vs. Dynamic SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am observing very different rendering for static vs. dynamic SVG. Consider the following snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Dynamic SVG</title>
  <script>
    window.onload = (event) => {
      let svgNS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
      let xlinkNS = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink';
      let div = document.createElement('div');
      let svg = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'svg');
      svg.classList.add('dynamic');
      // try commented out also
      svg.setAttributeNS(svgNS, 'viewBox', '-8 -8 40 40');
      let useTag = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'use');
      useTag.setAttributeNS(xlinkNS, 'xlink:href', '#menu');
      svg.appendChild(useTag);
      div.appendChild(svg);
      document.body.appendChild(div);
    };

  </script>

</head>

<body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="display: none;">
      <symbol id="menu">
        <path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm-4.5 14c-.828 0-1.5-.672-1.5-1.5s.672-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.672 1.5 1.5-.672 1.5-1.5 1.5zm4.5 0c-.828 0-1.5-.672-1.5-1.5s.672-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.672 1.5 1.5-.672 1.5-1.5 1.5zm4.5 0c-.828 0-1.5-.672-1.5-1.5s.672-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.672 1.5 1.5-.672 1.5-1.5 1.5z" />
      </symbol>
    </svg>
    <div>
    <!-- <svg class="static"> -->
    <svg class="static" viewBox="-8 -8 40 40">
      <use xlink:href="#menu"></use>
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This renders in Chrome and Firefox as follows:

[image]

The static SVG tag is enormous, while the dynamic SVG is tiny. However, if you examine the HTML in DevTools:

[image]

You can see that the final markup for both SVG is exactly the same. The only difference is one is static in the HTML, the other is created dynamically via javascript.

However, if I change the snippet so that the SVG tags do not have a viewBox attribute, the rendering is quite different:

[image]

This is the expected outcome: same markup produces the same rendering.

So, my question is: Why does the same viewBox attribute produce such radically different renderings: static vs. dynamic?

FYI: This snippet is a very simplified version of a project I'm working on. I use the viewBox to size and position glyphs on button tags. The SVG path was created with viewBox="0 0 24 24". The viewbox="-8 -8 40 40" is designed to zoom out and center the glyph onto a 48px square button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewBox` attribute doesn't need a special NameSpace. The one you added is not standard and thus not recognized by the browser.

```js
svg.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'viewBox', '0 0 100 100');

console.log('no namespace', svg.getAttribute('viewBox')); // "50 50 50 50"
console.log('svgNS', svg.getAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'viewBox')); // "0 0 100 100"
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="50 50 50 50"></svg>
```

Use `setAttribute('viewBox', '-8 -8 40 40')` and you'll be fine.

```js
let svgNS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
let xlinkNS = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink';
let div = document.createElement('div');
let svg = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'svg');
svg.classList.add('dynamic');

svg.setAttribute('viewBox', '-8 -8 40 40');
let useTag = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'use');
useTag.setAttributeNS(xlinkNS, 'xlink:href', '#menu');
svg.appendChild(useTag);
div.appendChild(svg);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="menu">
    <path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm-4.5 14c-.828 0-1.5-.672-1.5-1.5s.672-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.672 1.5 1.5-.672 1.5-1.5 1.5zm4.5 0c-.828 0-1.5-.672-1.5-1.5s.672-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.672 1.5 1.5-.672 1.5-1.5 1.5zm4.5 0c-.828 0-1.5-.672-1.5-1.5s.672-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.672 1.5 1.5-.672 1.5-1.5 1.5z" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
<div>
  <svg class="static" viewBox="-8 -8 40 40">
    <use xlink:href="#menu"></use>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Kaiido! You are correct. I had erroneously followed some examples I googled which were using a namespace. You just saved me hours of frustration.

Comment: An excellent reference to amplify Kaiido's answer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course